# while running JUnit, FileNotFoundException , text files are not found located in src/test/resource folder

Tags: java, maven, junit, build, resources

Application runs in production environment and there is no change in code since long time.

After setting up application in eclipse in local machine, I am trying to run JUnits and they are failing due to resources file not found located in src/test/resources folder in Java maven project directory.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'C:\[redacted]\target\test-classes\sample.txt' does not exist
```

In code, files are read through below code.

```
String content = IOUtils.toString(openInputStream(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename).getPath()), "UTF-8")
```

NOTE: application has been set up before also without any issue of JUnits.
application is passed through Jenkin build JUnit check also.
I am able to run my application in eclipse.

So there should be something missing at eclipse setting or build path. Please guide me.

Comment: Q: do you have a "<testresources>" entry in your Maven pom.xml?  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18082816/421195

Comment: `C:*\target\test-classes\sample-*.txt` I don't think the leading asterisk in the path will work here unless you're using a path matcher.

Comment: asterisk was placed only to hide real folder structure. I updated it in my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a text-file resource into Java unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891375/how-to-read-a-text-file-resource-into-java-unit-test)

Comment: I've tried all other options. I was able to run JUnits some months before  without any issues. No code changes since then. Now there is some issue with eclipse or build path.